# Creating WiFi network from wired LAN without needing a PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection

I am moving to a hostel in France where they provide wired LAN connection. I do not possess a laptop and use internet on my iPad and smartphone.
Does plugging in the LAN cable into the WiFi router create a WiFi network so that i can connect my devices?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes it does - though it won't work with some hotels as they have measures to prevent it

Comment: You need to have gateways and DNS address, so that you can configure that in your router

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. You can buy a router and connect the LAN wire to it and you can use internet from your portable devices (I did the same in my first semester).

Comment: It's not as easy as that. As per Paul's comment, there may be certain restrictions set in place.